# browseForDirectory fails on Windows 7 with File.documentsDirectory as root

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Odd, non-cross platform behavior here: in an AIR app, I want to open a directory browse window.

On OSX I use this code and it works fine (*projectDirectory* has been declared earlier as type `File`:

```
projectDirectory = File.documentsDirectory;
projectDirectory.browseForDirectory("Select Project Directory");
```

but it fails on Windows 7: no directory browser opens. However if I specify the `userDirectory` I *do* get a directory browser:

```
projectDirectory = File.userDirectory;
projectDirectory.browseForDirectory("Select Project Directory");
```

According to the Adobe AIR docs, both these File directory constants are valid for each platform so I am confused. I've fiddled with it and tried various things but I can't get File.documentsDirectory` to work on WIndows 7. Has anyone seen this before?

My dev environment is OSX and I am running Windows 7 as an admin user through VMWare so maybe that is the culprit but I would expect total failure if that were the case.

---

**Update**

Odd - with `File.documentsDirectory` I don't get an error and don't even see the "BEFORE" btn click msg but with
`File.userDirectory` I see the msgs and the directory browser opens as expected.

```
            //projectDirectory = File.documentsDirectory;

            projectDirectory = File.userDirectory;

            try{
                projectDirectoryPathField.text += "BEFORE button clicked \n";
                projectDirectory.browseForDirectory("Select Project Directory");
                projectDirectoryPathField.text += "AFTER button clicked \n";

            } catch(error:SecurityError){
                projectDirectoryPathField.text += error.errorID +" \n";
                projectDirectoryPathField.text += error.message +" \n";
                projectDirectoryPathField.text += error.name +" \n";
            }
```

Comment: Try to use a `try` and `catch` to catch error, or add a `SecurityError` event, I think that your application didn't have the necessary permissions to access to that dir.

Comment: NP on windows 7 for me or any windows.